# How to get scrolling plot in Linux (using command-line tools)?

Tags: linux, command-line, charts

Supposing I have a program that prints lines with data periodically, how can I turn then info them into graphical plot that updates itself each time new line available?

```
$ ./prog
10 44
20 66
30 55
40 58
50 59
55 58
60 77
^C

$ ./prog | scrollingplot

Window appears and updates on each line printed:

80|                             
  |                        ----   
  |   ----     ______...__/
  |  /    -----
  | -
40|
-------------------------------
    10  20  30   40   50    60

# Note that ASCII art-style plot is just for example, 
# I want simple X window like in mplayer.
```

There are enough tools for static data, but I haven't seen ones for updating data (except of `ksysguard`).

Comment: Note that I don't want plot in ASCII Art style, it is just to show that there's a plot. I want some GUI window to appear like in `mplayer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can run Perl, you could look into this script that seems to do exactly what you want. It is using [GnuPlot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) for displaying the plot.

http://users.softlab.ece.ntua.gr/~ttsiod/gnuplotStreaming.html

GnuPlot is powerful and has many features. If you want to learn more about it, try googling for [gnuplot tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?q=gnuplot+tutorial).

Comment: +1; very cool script (through it takes some time to ^C it ;), and it uses *the* feature-rich gnuplot.

Comment: Example: `for((;;)) { cat /proc/loadavg | grep -o '^[^ ]*' | sed 's/^/0:/' ; sleep 1; } | driveGnuPlotStreams.pl 1 40 0 2  qqq  0`

Comment: Better alternative: git://github.com/dkogan/feedgnuplot.git. After adding option `-noraise` to `gnuplot` and making `--stream` and `--lines` the default it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm thinking too simple, but: Clear screen with `clear` and re-execute the plotting program?

Comment: I want GUI tool (same GUI-ness level as `display` or `mplayer`) that also can displays coordinate axis, display smooth lines and so on.

Comment: Check "aalib" for this purpose. | http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/aalib_16.html#SEC16

Comment: @Shiki I depicted the plot as AA doesn't means I want the result in AA. It just symbolizes that the plot is drawn.

Comment: Well.. Uhm.. I meant the -vo aa in mplayer for example. ^^" (I'll ask a friend of mine tomorrow, maybe he'll know a good one. As far as I know him, he'll know one. :))